# How to grep one string after pattern?

Tags: linux, grep

I would like to get the string from the file after user defined keyword. Example if keyword is "yellow_y", expected output to be acc.

Tried `grep -oP '(?<=yellow_y).*'` but not work.

File:

```
yellow      abc \
yellow_x     abc \
yellow_y      acc \
blue     abb \
pink abb \
pink_xx acd \
```

Comment: It seems another case for `awk`, `awk '$1 == "yellow_y"{print $2}' file`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match

Comment: It works fine here, which version og grep is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `grep` command. Written and tested in GNU `grep`.

```
grep -oP '^yellow_y\s+\K\S+'  Input_file
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/2Rqoip/1/)

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `-oP` options of GNU `grep` which is for printing matched words and enabling PCRE regex respectively. In main program using regex to match condition. Checking if line starts from yellow_y followed by 1 or more spaces then using `\K` capability of GNU `grep` to forget this match and matching 1 or more non-spaces characters then which will provide required values in output.

Comment: Do you know where the \K is mentioned in the manual / info pages? maybe this? https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Extended-Patterns (would have never guessed \K means that)

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин, Honestly I learnt it from Gurus in SO itself, after your comment I checked man pages and help but couldn't find it(at least in my grep version), but searching online I found this https://learnbyexample.gitbooks.io/command-line-text-processing/content/gnu_grep.html site which has it. But doesn't look like it mentions too many details about it(though they have given few examples for it).

Comment: thanks. I modify it based on my needs and it is working

Answer (score 0):

To get `acc`, you can also use `awk` here instead of `grep`:

```sh
awk '$1 == "yellow_y"{print $2}' file
```

This means: if the first word (first non-whitespace chunk) is `yellow_y`, return the second non-whitespace chunk of characters (the second word).

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/6hjzs5):

```
#!/bin/bash
s='yellow      abc \
yellow_x     abc \
yellow_y      acc \
blue     abb \
pink abb \
pink_xx acd \'
awk '$1 == "yellow_y"{print $2}' <<< "$s"
```

Output is `acc`.